# How to discover the last time  SQL Server was restarted?

Tags: sql-server

What command could be used to discover the last datetime SQL Server was restarted?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT MIN ([login_time]) FROM sysprocesses;
```

Source:

- ["What is the current uptime of SQL Server?"](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-18-Whats-the-current-uptime-of-SQL-Server.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you talking about Microsoft's SQL Server 2005 or above, MSDN's docs about sys.databases [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx):

> create_date 
>   Date the database was created or renamed. For tempdb, this value changes every time the server restarts.

So, this should be what you need:

```
SELECT create_date FROM sys.databases WHERE NAME='tempdb'
```

Comment: Then both mine and Matt's answers will do.

Comment: thanks for the above.. I have one more question, If master got corrupted or in suspect we will rebuild system databases if we rebuild the system databases what will happen to existing data. and I need step by step procedure for how to solve MSDB suspect/sorrupt state...

Comment: I don't known (never happen to me) but MSDN has [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx) procedure to rebuild the system databases. Has for the data, I'm assuming you will lose it (the data in the suspected database) but once again, I have never gone through that. Best of luck!

Comment: If the suspected database is one of the system databases, see the link I gave you in my previous comment. Otherwise, see [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2174/sql-server-suspect-database).